# Decompression of payload in my webservice

Tags: web-services, axis, http-compression

How to process an incoming Payload(SOAP) which is **COMPRESSED**, in my webservices which I have created using Axis ???

Comment: what do you mean by compressed ? gzip encoded ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'r content is GZip Encoded

1.Check the content encoding. If it is **gzip** then

2.wrapper the input stream as a `GZIPInputStream`

read as usual from input stream.

Comment: thank you. But could you please elaborate. 

Basically what i am doing is. I have a WSDL and i have hosted a web service using top down approach in eclipse using AXIS runtime. If the request to the webservice is sent in an uncompressed way everything works perfect. But if the request is sent in compressed way it fails.So how can i handle compressed request to uncompress it before i get hold of it..

Comment: detailed [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-sqzsoap/index.html) - old but bang on to the point.

Comment: Thank you again..But this deals with modifying axis jar and plugging back. Is there any other way where we can intercept and uncompress it before Axis reads the xml and puts the data in the stubs.

Comment: you can always have a SOAP Listener, which intercepts the SOAP messages